Mypy does not see my singleton class attribute. It throws [attr-defined] and [no-untyped-def]
class WaitService:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, name: str = "Default"):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(WaitService, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls._instance.name = name
        return cls._instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = WaitService("at till 9pm")

    print(w.name)


I have a python singleton class above. It runs as expected but when I validate it with Mypy, I get the errors below. Any ideas on how to resolve this
error: "WaitService" has no attribute "name"  [attr-defined]
error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def]


None of this is specific to your singleton implementation. Those are both general type errors that mean exactly what they say: you're attempting to assign to an undeclared attribute (name), and you have a function that's missing a return annotation (__new__)

I don't use mypy, but putting name: str at the top under _instance = None should fix that:
class WaitService:
    _instance = None
    name: str

You haven't indicated anywhere that the class has a name instance attribute, so the error makes sense.
Note that the "declaration" appears by the class vars because somewhat confusingly, names declared there with a type are considered to be instance members, not class ones. You could also hint _instance as well:
class WaitService:
    _instance: ClassVar[Optional['WaitService']] = None
    name: str


"names declared there with a type are considered to be instance members, not class ones" This is only true for dataclasses

Also, I'd just use Optional[Self] for _instance's annotation, if anything.

@DeepSpace Nope. This is some bizarre new rule they created. See here: "In particular, the value-less notation a: int allows one to annotate instance variables that should be initialized in init or new."

The fact that dataclasses already use that syntax might have been a motivating factor.

Well, as it only affects type checking and not runtime behavior I guess it's ok :)

@DeepSpace and Carcigenicate, PEP 526 was accepted before 3.6. Dataclasses were first introduced in 3.7. These type hints can also be introspected at runtime; try printing out such a class's .__annotations__ attribute.
